# Saving data to 2 tables with same identifier (for joining)

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I am writing a excel parser in Python using pandas.

I want to write data to 2 separate tables. Product Data table and Values table. The values table will have values for multiple days (product sales per day) and a product data will be product data as the name implies.

`ProductData: ProductId, Name, Description`

`Values: ProductId, Date, Units Sold, Sold at`

Can someone help me using pandas or python create unique product ids in sql (auto increment id) and somehow pass that id to the second table so `productdata.product_1 == value.product_1`?

I don't really want to loop through each row or manually add product id's as there is about 2k products.

Example of Table Data:

```
ProductData:
|-----------|------------------|-----------------------------|
| ProductId | Name             | Description                 |
|-----------|------------------|-----------------------------|
| 1         | Quinny Pushchair | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  |
| 2         | iCandy Pushchair | consectetur adipiscing elit |
| 3         | Maxi Pushchair   | sed do eiusmod tempor       |
|-----------|------------------|-----------------------------|
```

```
Values:
|-----------|---------------|-------------|------------|
| ProductId | Date          | Units Sold  | Sold at    |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|------------|
| 1         | 2019-12-28    | 0           | 300.00     |
| 1         | 2019-12-29    | 3           | 300.00     |
| 1         | 2019-12-30    | 5           | 300.00     |
| 1         | 2019-12-31    | 1           | 300.00     |
| 2         | 2019-12-28    | 7           | 600.00     |
| 2         | 2019-12-29    | 1           | 600.00     |
| 2         | 2019-12-30    | 3           | 600.00     |
| 2         | 2019-12-31    | 5           | 600.00     |
| 3         | 2019-12-28    | 0           | 360.00     |
| 3         | 2019-12-29    | 0           | 360.00     |
| 3         | 2019-12-30    | 3           | 360.00     |
| 3         | 2019-12-31    | 2           | 360.00     |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in table 2, "product id" is unique. 
In which case, you don't have a problem, your already have unique product ids, in table 2. So make that column the primary key.

table 1 does not have a primary key. In this case, your idea of an auto-incrementing column is correct. It is irrelevant to your need to join the two tables: in your question, you already have the answer to that.

If I don't understand your question, please illustrate with some code attempts.

Comment: Ahh I explained it badly. You're correct table 2 product id is unique not table 1. In table 1 a composite key of product id and day would be used. Currently the excel file doesn't have product id's at all, I want to basically make it that when the script is run, it converts the data into 2 tables, in table 2 it give the product an id say 1,2,3... and it when saving each product to the db it returns the auto id so the other table can do product 1, 2020-01-01, 3...

Comment: right now as I do not have any shared keys I would not be able to join the tables. I write a loop that inserts a single row into the db, returns the latest rows id, throws it to the current column in the dataframe then saves 1 product with all its data in the value table, and repeats however this is innefficent... hope that makes sense

Comment: You should give code  examples. It does not sound like a very difficult problem. The first thing I would do is build the data for both tables in a dict for each table, and write the dicts out at the end of your read of the excel data. This is one pass.

Comment: Sorry for delay in responding, been away from the xmas break. I shall update the original question with some code tomorrow and rephrase the question.